# How to check if Generating Function is correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations, generating-functions, characteristic-functions

I have the following sequence given recursively by:

$$A_n - 2A_{n-1} - 4A_{n-2} = 0$$

Where:

$$A_0 = 1, A_1 = 3, A_2 = 10, A_3 = 32, etc.$$

To find the generating function, I have done the following:

$$\begin{aligned} A &= 1 + 3x + 10x^2 + 32x^3 + \dots 
\\ -2xA &= 0 - 2x - 6x^2 - 20x^3 + \dots 
\\ -4x^2 A &= 0 - 0 - 4x^2 - 12x^3 + \dots \end{aligned}$$

[NOTE: The $0s$ are there for formatting purposes, they're not part of the expressions]

Adding these together:

$$(1 - 2x - 4x^2)A = 1 + x + 0$$

$$A = \frac{1+x}{1 - 2x - 4x^2}$$

Which, I'm guessing, gives me the generating function.

My question is, how do I know if this is correct? What is this generating function supposed to tell me?

If I substitute certain values into the generating function, will I get the initial sequence given recursively or will I get the function, $A = 1 + 3x + 10x^2 + 32x^3 + ...$?

Comment: you don't usually substitute values for $x$ in the generating function $A$, you usually work with $\dfrac{A^{(n)}}{n!}$ ($A^{(n)}$ is the $n^{th}$ derivative of $A$ with respect to $x$) which gives you the coefficient of $x^n$ in the generating function, which is actually the $n^{th}$ term of the sequence.

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3 Yeah, I'd like to know how that works exactly.

Comment: See if [this](http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi2/section-27.html) helps. There is always the reference to [generatingfunctionology](https://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf)

Comment: You can write $1 - 2x - 4x^2=-4(x-\alpha_1)(x-\alpha_2)$ where $\alpha_1,\alpha_2$ are roots of the quadratic, and then use partial fractions decomposition to get $\frac{1+x}{1 - 2x - 4x^2}=\frac{A_1}{\alpha_1-x}+\frac{A_2}{\alpha_2-x}$. where each of the terms can be written as geometric series $\frac{A_i}{\alpha_i-x}=\frac{A_i}{\alpha_i}\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{\alpha_i}}=\frac{A_i}{\alpha_i}(1+\frac{x}{\alpha_i}+(\frac{x}{\alpha_i})^ 2+\dots)$. So you can read off the coefficients at $x_n$ easily to get closed form for $A_n$, and possibly verify with values given by recurrence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do polynomial long division to grind out as many terms as you like. (Sorry for the image, trying to figure out how to do this with MathJax made me grow faint.)

[image: polynomial long division]

Answer (score 0):

To answer your literal question, you can have software expand your rational function to make sure the first terms are correct, [like this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5B%281%2Bx%29%2F%281-2x-4x%5E2%29%2C%20%7Bx%2C0%2C50%7D%5D).